# how to find records that column "c2" repeated 2 times by hql

Tags: hibernate, hql

there is a table named  "tableA",
the column(first row)   and records as below:

```
"id"          "c2"          "c3"   
1             zhan1        wu
2             zhan1        go
3             chan1        th
4             zhuang       cn
```

now,you can see "zhan1" repeated 2 times in column "c2"
so I want find the first record and second record by HQL.
and I know how to use sql resolve this problem:

```
select a from tableA a inner join
 (select b.c2 from tableA b group by b.c2 having count(b.c2)=2 ) c  on  a.c2=c.c2
```

some one knows how to use HQL resolve this probelm??? thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first" and "second" record in a SQL table.  You have to specify a means by which to order the duplicate records.

Comment: first record mean  id=1 and second mean id=2,and I know how to use sql，but don't know how to use hql in hibernate